# Get users in multiple ADgroups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this script that extracts the users that belong to the groups I need.

```
$GroupList = Get-Content C:\Scripts\grouplist.txt

$Results = foreach ($Group in $GroupList) {
$Description = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | 
    Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Name, @{Name='GroupName';Expression={$Group}}, @{Name='Description';Expression={$Description}}
}

$Results

$Results | Export-csv -Path C:\Scripts\SecurityGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is that I only need users in the enabled state.

And I can't. Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Once you have the `$results` populated, u can run them through the `Get-Aduser` cmdlet and filter them by their `Enabled` property.

Comment: Do you want all members, including groups? Or only users?

Comment: Adding the "Enabled" filter returns all AD users in this state. (Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true})

Comment: Bergmann i need only users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned per the comments you can use the `Get-Aduser` cmdlet after you populated your results. Here you have to filter out groups, otherwise the cmdlet will throw exceptions for every group.

```
$results = @()
foreach ($group in $grouplist) {
  $description = (Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description
  $members = Get-ADGroupMember $group | ?{$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | % {Get-ADUser $_ -Properties enabled}
  $results += $members | ? {$_.Enabled -eq $true } | select samaccountname, name, @{name='groupname';expression={$group}}, @{name='description';expression={$description}}
}
```

Alternatively, you can use LDAP-filters. This option is noticeably faster since you only make one request per group, not one per user.

```
$results = @()
foreach ($group in $grouplist) {
  $group = Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description
  $members = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$($group.DistinguishedName))(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))"
  $results += $members | select samaccountname, name, @{name='groupname';expression={$group}}, @{name='description';expression={$group.description}}
}
```

With LDAP-filters you could also request members of multiple groups at once, but since you want the context in which group a user was found this is not an option here..

Comment: It worked with the first option. Thank you so much.